# How to call one block function to another block in same module

Tags: module, blocks, magento2.4.1

**First Block:**

```
app\code\Zero\Storelocator\Block\view\Attributes.php

function name : getLocationAttributes()
```

**Second Block:**

```
app\code\Zero\Storelocator\Block\Customerreview.php
```

***How to get the first block function values ?***

Answer (score 0):

You can get this file in customerreview.php and call function from that file.

```
<?php
namespace Zero\Storelocator\Block;

class Customerreview extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{     
     public function __construct(
        \Zero\Storelocator\Block\view\Attributes $attributes,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
        array $data = []
     ) {
        $this->$attributes = $attributes;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }   

    public function getCustomerReview(){    

       echo $this->$attributes->getLocationAttributes();
        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hi, i am getting this error : Error: Object of class Zero\Storelocator\Block\View\Attributes could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\m3\app\code\Zero\Storelocator\Block\Customerreview.php:21

Screenshot : https://snipboard.io/URcLt3.jpg

Comment: attribute.php https://paste.ofcode.org/ZXffpxtY5wHDjNkn6SaciZ

Comment: remove echo from line no.21 and use print_r() to print the value of attributes.

Comment: In attribute.php log return values, when i print values in Customerreview.php log not generated and return  Error: Call to a member function getAttributes() on null, Can you pls help me on that, i posted new post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/336603/57334

Comment: FYI I am trying to pass the value third-party module block to the custom module block.